# How to solve property error when trying to convert multiple ranges into values?

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, colors

All, I'm new to VBA and am teaching myself... I am getting a property error when trying to change a range's formulas... the range can be found at the bottom of the code. How do you make these cells turn to values without throwing an error?

```
Sub InvestorModelMacro()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    DisplayGridlines = False

    Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet

    For Each r In Worksheets("Asset Dashboard").Range("C6:C9")   'go through each cell in DV list
        If Len(r) > 0 Then                                       'only do something if cell not empty
            Worksheets("Live").Range("D3").Value = r.Value        'transfer value to cell D3 of 'Live' tab
            Application.Calculate
            Set ws = Worksheets.Add                               'add new sheet
            ws.Name = Worksheets("Investor Model").Range("D3")    'renames new sheet after selected asset
            Worksheets("Investor Model").Cells.Copy
            ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormulas                'copy values only from Investor Model to new sheet
            ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats                 'copy formats only from Investor Model to new sheet
            ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False                 'turns off gridlines
            ws.Range("F46:G52,G54,G56:G58,G60:G61,G65:G72,G75:G80,G87,G89:G92").Values
            ws.Range("F46:G52,G54,G56:G58,G60:G61,G65:G72,G75:G80,G87,G89:G92").Font.Color = vbBlue

        End If
    Next r

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You'd call `.Value` = `.Value` on the range, but this doesn't work for a multi-area range (where the cells are not all contiguous).

Comment: `PasteSpecial xlFormulas` pastes formulas - did you mean to paste values?

Comment: @ BigBen, I see, so do I just need to break out the multi-area range and individually convert the cells to values?

Comment: @Tim, I want a majority of my new worksheets to show formulas, just the cells in the range need to be values.

Answer (score 1):

At most you can use Areas

```
Dim Area As Range
'...
For Each Area In ws.Range("F46:G52,G54,G56:G58,G60:G61,G65:G72,G75:G80,G87,G89:G92").Areas
    Area.Value = Area.Value
    Area.Font.Color = vbBlue
Next Area
```